# I m facing error in Microsoft Synchframework 2.1 Error:Invalid column name

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestingSynch
{
    public static class PosSynch
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Decaription:Parmaeter
        /// </summary>
        static string sServerConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["POSServer"];
        static string sClientConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["POSClient"];

        static string sScope;


        /// <summary>
        /// Description:Set Server Provision Descritpion Table
        /// </summary>
        public static void ProvisionServer()
        {

            SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection(sServerConnection);
            SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(sClientConnection); 
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
            sScope = GetScope();
            Dt = GetServerTable();
            DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(sScope);
            for (int i = 0; i <= Dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                DbSyncTableDescription tableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(Dt.Rows[i][0].ToString(), serverConn);
                scopeDesc.Tables.Add(tableDesc);
            }
            Provision(scopeDesc, serverConn);







        }

        public static void Provision(DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc, SqlConnection serverConn)
         {

            SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn, scopeDesc);
            serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
            serverProvision.Apply();
        }


        public static void Deprovision(SqlConnection serverConn,SqlConnection clientconnection)
        {
            SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning objServer = new SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(serverConn);
            SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning objClient = new SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(clientconnection);
            DataTable dtserver = new DataTable();
            DataTable dtclient = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                string query = null;
                query = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScopInfo"];
                serverConn = new SqlConnection(sServerConnection);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, serverConn);
                sda.Fill(dtserver);

                foreach (var item in dtserver.Rows)
                {
                    objServer.DeprovisionScope(item.ToString());

                }


                query = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScopInfo"];
                serverConn = new SqlConnection(sClientConnection);
                SqlDataAdapter sdac = new SqlDataAdapter(query, clientconnection);
                sda.Fill(dtclient);
                foreach (var item in dtclient.Rows)
                {
                    objClient.DeprovisionScope(item.ToString());

                }



            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                dtclient.Dispose();
                dtserver.Dispose();
            }

            //    return null;


            //obj.DeprovisionTemplate(scopeDesc.ScopeName);
            //foreach (var item in scopeDesc.Tables)
            //{
            //    obj.DeprovisionTemplate(item.LocalName.ToString());
            //}

        }




        public static DataTable GetServerTable()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Tables");
            try
            {
                //string query = null;
                //query = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerTableQuery"];
                //SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection(sServerConnection);
                //SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, serverConn);
                //sda.Fill(dt);
                //dt.Rows.Add("POSEmailSetting");
                //dt.Rows.Add("UserDetails");
                //dt.Rows.Add("ParkingRequestHistory");
                //dt.Rows.Add("Logins");
                dt.Rows.Add("ParkingRequestMaster");
                //dt.Rows.Add("ParkingRequestProductOrderDetail");
                //dt.Rows.Add("ParkingYardMaster");
                //dt.Rows.Add("PosLogRecords");

                return dt;
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                dt.Dispose();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Description Create New Scope While Hitting Server
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetScope()
        {
            Random objrand = new Random();
            sScope = "SyncTableScope_" + objrand.Next().ToString();
            return sScope;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Description:Set Client Provision Description Table
        /// </summary>

        public static void ProvisionClient()
        {
            SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection(sServerConnection);
            SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(sClientConnection);
            DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope(sScope, serverConn);
            //DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(sScope, serverConn);
          //  DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(sScope, serverConn);
            SqlSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn, scopeDesc);
            var text =  clientProvision.Script();
            clientProvision.Apply();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Description :Synchronized Data Between Client & Server Apps
        /// </summary>

        public static void Sync()
        {
            SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection(sServerConnection);
            SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(sClientConnection);
            SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(sScope, clientConn);
            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(sScope, serverConn);
            syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.DownloadAndUpload;
            ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);
            SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
            Console.WriteLine("Start Time: " + syncStats.SyncStartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Uploaded: " + syncStats.UploadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Downloaded: " + syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Complete Time: " + syncStats.SyncEndTime);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Program_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Conflict.Type);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
        }

    }
}

While Provisoning Server Db ,in I m facing error  Invallid Coloumn name
```

Invalid column name 'BookingSource'.
Invalid column name 'IsCheckedIn'.
Invalid column name 'FlightDetails'.
Invalid column name 'CheckedOutBy'.
Invalid column name 'CheckedInBy'.
Invalid column name 'IsCheckedOut'.
Invalid column name 'ParkedAtLocation'.

Comment: Do you know what database you are connecting to? What do you know about the schema of this database?

Comment: are there existing scope on the server containing the same table?

Comment: it's Resolve the  issue was that i  had not arrange table in Primary & foreign key relation therefore  during provisioning server  it's not Create Scope at  Attempt and giving error invallid column name in Primary key realtional table......anyway thanks